# What other non-default ports can i use for webserver?

Tags: ports

I am using 80(http) and 443(https) default ports for my webserver.
What ther ports other than this can i use for my webserver. 
I need this basically to start my webserver using non-default ports.

Comment: Any port from 1 to 65535 should work, as long as it's not used for anything else on that server.

Answer (score 0):

Any.  Look at these for the ones to not use:

http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_TCP_and_UDP_port_numbers

Answer (score 0):

You can use whatever ports you *want* to use, provided no other server on your box is also trying to use it.

This is, of course, subject to any OS-specific issues like needing to run with elevated privileges for binding to ports below 1024.

The IANA (naming authority) and ICANN (assigned names and numbers) is responsible for assigning ports to specific applications but there's nothing requiring you to *follow* those "rules" at all.

If you use (for example) port 23 for your HTTP server, that will work. It's likely to confuse any telnet programs attempting to connect to that box but, as stated, the box is under your jurisdiction, not that of the IANA. Provided your browsers hook up to the specific port 23, they'll work just fine.

By way of example, many IBM mainframe systems will use port 23 for their 3270-protocol terminal programs and bump "real" telnet up to port 1023.

And, in any case, why should you not use a port because it's "allocated" to the Quake game server, or Dropbox, or Symantec bloatware? :-)

Comment: When i use port 23 it throws me error saying Error code: ERR_UNSAFE_PORT

Comment: That's because ports under 1024 are considered special under some operating systems. Your process will need to be running elevated, such as under the root user. Updated the answer. It also depends on what's actually throwing that error.